# Get ID of the record from list of Account

Tags: apex

How do i get the id of each record from which i inserted using list collection.

```
List<Training__c> lsttra = new List<Training__c>{
        new training__c(Name = 'BulkMaster1'),
        new training__c(Name = 'BulkMaster2'),
        new training__c(Name = 'BulkMaster3')
};
insert lsttra;
```

I want to get id of each records which i inserted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could refer to the objects by their position in the list:

```
system.debug(lsttra[0]);
```

or loop through the list if you want the id from all of the objects:

```
for(Training__c t : lsttra){
    system.debug(t.Id);
}
```